# Python turtle listen for onkey

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there a way to write a turtle onkey() statement so it will listen for any letter key, or can you only specify a single key in each onkey() statement? I don't want to have 26 onkey(), one set up for each letter "a", "b",... etc.

I want to write a simple tickertape display where every time you type a letter it adds the letter to the end of the string being written by the turtle and moves the display across by one letter.

Comment: Yes, by not specifying *any* key to `onkey()`, your handler will trigger on all keys.  (I.e. leave off the second argument.)  However, there's glitch.  When your handler fires, you won't know which key triggered it!  Here's a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59914207/5771269) to get the behavior you describe.

Comment: Many thanks. That's really useful to know that any key will trigger onkey() if you don't specify a key. I'll investigate the workaround to determine which key was pressed.

Comment: Hi, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780485/python-turtle-check-if-a-key-is-down